# Laravel 5 pretty URL not working on wamp

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel, I am working over a small project, using wamp. I was facing problem with pretty URL part, which I figured it out just now.

But now I am getting a weird issue. I have created my application under directory **laravel-first-app**. 
When I am trying to request a page (articles) for example, **http://localhost/laravel-first-app/public/index.php/cv**, it is showing up the page.

But now if, I request a page for example, **http://localhost/laravel-first-app/public/cv**, it is saying **URL Not Found** error.

Below is a brief description what I did.

In my routes.php

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);

Route::resource('articles','ArticlesController');
Route::get('articles/delete/{article_id}','ArticlesController@destroy');

Route::get('cv','CvController@index');
Route::get('cv/upload','CvController@upload');
Route::post('cv','CvController@store');
```

In my CvController

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class CvController extends Controller {

    private $pathToCV;
    private $fileName;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->pathToCV="cv/";
        $this->fileName='piyush_cv.doc';
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return response()->download($this->pathToCV.$this->fileName);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        return view('cv.upload');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd($request);
        if($request->hasFile('cv'))
        {
            $file = $request->file('cv');
            $file->move($this->pathToCV,$this->fileName);
            flash()->overlay('File Uploaded','Thanks for uploading the file');
            return redirect('cv/upload');
        }
        flash()->overlay('File was not selected','');
        return redirect('cv/upload');

    }

}
```

In .htaccess I have:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Also, for my wamp, I have enabled **mod_rewrite** module.

Can you please help me out with this? I want to use url **http://localhost/laravel-first-app/public/cv** instead of **http://localhost/laravel-first-app/public/index.php/cv**

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked carefully to the application structure, I figured out what was the problem.

Now, I resolved the issue and every thing is working fine.

In the Controller, CvController, I had sent a directory CV, and path name was also CV, so it was behaving weirdly.

If you want detailed solution for this, let me know.

Thanks anyways.

Comment: Can you please add what you did?

Answer (score 0):

go to the project folder, open terminal and then run `php artisan serve` it will start localhost:8000 or similar like that then simply go to `https://localhost:8000/articles` for your required page

Comment: I tried it but it is not launching localhost:8000, terminal is throwing an error that CLI stopped working.

Comment: If you are in windows then you need to set php environment variable to run any php command.

Comment: I have the php enviornment set on my system. Even though it is not working.

Comment: i got it working .. with some other method that I tried ... thanks anyways @try_simple_code